# armature keyframe timeline?

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

hey all a quick question here , so I have this armature (object mode ) which is already animated as keyframes , when I go to pose mode to animate every bone , the keyframe of the object mode are in the timeline with the pose mode keyframe? I m just confused , and how to make every bone or armature have a keyframe on it own ?
best regard[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the *Dope Sheet* and activate the *Only Show Selected* option, you'll only see the keyframes of the selected bone(s). Note that in the same action you'll also see the keyframe of the armature object as well if you've keyframed it. If you've keyframed the armature object (in *Object* mode) as well as its bones (in *Pose* mode), both these keyframes will be part of the same action. That's why it may be better to parent your object to an empty, this way you'll keyframe the empty, not the armature object itself.

[image]